# Loop While using createAccountWithEmailAndPassword function in next js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

this is the error i am getting

```
action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.936
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.936
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.937
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.937
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.938
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.938
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.939
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.939
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
```

```
// Function for creating new User with email and password
export const createAccountWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => { 
    const auth = getAuth();
    dispatch(authActions.requestStart());

    try {
        await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);

        const user = await createAccountWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

        const idToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
        
        dispatch(authActions.requestSuccess(user , idToken));
        console.log('email Signup Worked Perfectly ');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        dispatch(authActions.requestFail(err.message));
        dispatch(authActions.resetAuth());
        console.log('Sign up Failed');
    }
};
```

this is my authActions

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: {
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        idToken: null,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        requestStart(state, action) {
            state.loading = true;
        },
        loadUser(state, action) {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.idToken = action.payload.idToken;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.loading = false;
        },
        logOut(state, action) {
            state.user = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.idToken = null;
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = null;
        },
        resetAuth(state, action) {
            state.user = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.idToken = null;
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = null;
        },
        requestFail(state, action) {
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export default authSlice.reducer;
export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
```

this is my auth reducer

and below is my code for register page

```
'use client'
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import routes from '@/config/routes';
import Navbar from '@/Components/Navbar';
import defaultTheme from '@/config/muiTheme';
import { createAccountWithGooglePopUp, createAccountWithEmailAndPassword } from '@/store/actions/auth';

export default function Register() {

    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleRegisterWithEmailAndPassword = async () => {
        await createAccountWithEmailAndPassword( email, password);
    };


    // function to register with googlePopUp
    const handleRegisterWithGooglePopUp =  () => { 
        createAccountWithGooglePopUp();
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
            <Navbar />
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                <CssBaseline />
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        marginTop: 20,
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                        <LockOutlinedIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Sign up
                    </Typography>
                    <Box component="form" noValidate sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                        <Grid container sx={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <TextField
                                autoComplete="name"
                                name="fullName"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="fullName"
                                label="Full Name"
                                autoFocus
                                value={fullName}
                                onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
                                sx={{
                                    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                                        borderColor: 'white',
                                    },
                                    '& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
                                        color: 'white',
                                    },
                                }}
                            />
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    id="email"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    name="email"
                                    autoComplete="email"
                                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                    sx={{
                                        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                                            borderColor: 'white',
                                        },
                                        '& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
                                            color: 'white',
                                        },
                                        mt: 2,
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    autoComplete="new-password"
                                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                    sx={{
                                        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                                            borderColor: 'white',
                                        },
                                        '& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
                                            color: 'white',
                                        },
                                        mt: 2,
                                        mb: 2,
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Button
                            type="button"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 1, border: '1px solid grey' }}
              onClick={handleRegisterWithEmailAndPassword}
                        >
                            Sign Up
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            type="button"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{ mt: 0, mb: 2, border: '1px solid grey' }}
                            onClick={handleRegisterWithGooglePopUp}
                        >
                            Create An Account With Google
                        </Button>
                        <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
                            <Grid item>
                                <Link href={routes.LOGIN_PAGE} sx={{ color: "white" }} variant="body2">
                                    Already have an account? Sign in
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

when i click on sign in button then i get these in the console
and after these i get failed request or the localhost crashed sometime these are just a few request but there are probably 1000 of these same request starting and failing and this is a loop of request start please help me if anyboady can help me i am stuck with this issue from 2 days and not able to solve it
i am using react and firebase

```
action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.936
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.936
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.937
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.937
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.938
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.938
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.939
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action auth/requestStart @ 22:09:03.939
VM20:6  prev state {auth: {…}}
VM20:6  action     {type: 'auth/requestStart', payload: undefined}
VM20:6  next state {auth: {…}}
```

this is the error i am getting please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Your `createAccountWithEmailAndPassword` function recursively calls itself.

```js
// Function for creating new User with email and password
export const createAccountWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => { 
  const auth = getAuth();
  dispatch(authActions.requestStart());

  try {
    await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);

    const user = await createAccountWithEmailAndPassword( // <-- recursive call!
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );

    const idToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
        
    dispatch(authActions.requestSuccess(user , idToken));
    console.log('email Signup Worked Perfectly ');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    dispatch(authActions.requestFail(err.message));
    dispatch(authActions.resetAuth());
    console.log('Sign up Failed');
  }
};
```

## Solution

I suspect that the inner `createAccountWithEmailAndPassword` is the Firebase function, so you should rename either it or ***your*** function using a different identifier so there's no name conflict.

Examples:

- **Rename the Firebase function:**

  ```js
  import {
    getAuth,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword as createUserWithEmailAndPasswordFirebase
  } from "firebase/auth";

  // Function for creating new User with email and password
  export const createAccountWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => { 
    const auth = getAuth();
    dispatch(authActions.requestStart());

    try {
      await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);

      const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPasswordFirebase(auth, email, password);

      const idToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();

      dispatch(authActions.requestSuccess(user , idToken));
      console.log('email Signup Worked Perfectly ');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      dispatch(authActions.requestFail(err.message));
      dispatch(authActions.resetAuth());
      console.log('Sign up Failed');
    }
  };
  ```

  ```js
  import { createAccountWithEmailAndPassword } from '@/store/actions/auth';

  ...

  const handleRegisterWithEmailAndPassword = () => {
    return createAccountWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };
  ```
- **Rename your function:**

  ```js
  import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

  // Function for creating new User with email and password
  export const createAccountWithEmailAndPasswordApp = async (email, password) => { 
    const auth = getAuth();
    dispatch(authActions.requestStart());

    try {
      await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);

      const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

      const idToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();

      dispatch(authActions.requestSuccess(user , idToken));
      console.log('email Signup Worked Perfectly ');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      dispatch(authActions.requestFail(err.message));
      dispatch(authActions.resetAuth());
      console.log('Sign up Failed');
    }
  };
  ```

  ```js
  import { createAccountWithEmailAndPasswordApp } from '@/store/actions/auth';

  ...

  const handleRegisterWithEmailAndPassword = () => {
    return createAccountWithEmailAndPasswordApp(email, password);
  };
  ```